# Posting a form with few thousand values 

Tags: php, post

I have this language based application that has language files for each part of the program for each language, eg:

```
// en.inc.php
$lang['main'] = 'this is my main string';
```

there are some files that have more that 2000 variables and I'm updating the translation in a web form I've created.

All of my language files that have few variables are updating flawless, the larger files simply stop at a random variables and my update script doesn't execute.

`post_max_size = 8M` - clearly my 2000 strings with 50-100 characters do not sum up to 8M of data (the file has ~100KB)

Last week all worked well, until I've updated PHP to `5.3.16`.

Did something change about post fields? I'm pretty sure there is something I am missing.
For some unidentified reason I'm not getting any errors even with `display_errors` turned on.

Comment: Are you using suhosin? http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.html#suhosin.post.max_vars

Comment: Have you checked the error log?

Comment: What is your `memory_limit` in your `php.ini`?

Comment: your strings may be <8meg, but there's overhead to consider as well - the field names, urlencoding, etc... all have to be counted as well.

Comment: Try running the script with `memory_get_peak_usage();`

Comment: Check the execution time limit (usually default is 30 seconds). It might be too short

Comment: not even with variable names and overhead I'm not getting at 1M, execution time last week was max 1 sec

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that many people are not aware of [**max_input_vars**](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#max_input_vars).  It was added in 5.3.9.

> "How many input variables may be accepted. Use of this directive
> mitigates the possibility of denial of service attacks which use hash
> collisions. If there are more input variables than specified by this
> directive, an E_WARNING is issued, and further input variables are
> truncated from the request. This limit applies only to each nesting
> level of a multi-dimensional input array."

Comment: uhmm, yes, but how could I forget if I didn't even see that setting :), updated, works. Thanks.

Comment: :) I'll reword that to "many people are not aware of", and not attack your memorization skills.  Glad its sorted for you.