# 1000 checked elements maximum in a post?

Tags: php, apache, post

I'm having trouble to understand something about Html forms :

I tried to send 50 000 checked checkboxes through a form (POST method), but a var_dump($_POST) tells me that there is only 1000 element in the array.

In local, the value is correct with 50 000 elements.

Is there a parameter somewhere in apache or php that limit the number of checked elements to be posted ?

Note : 
1) I tried to change post_max_size to 16M, and this limit is not reached.

2) The name of the inputs doesn't matter (same result with t1, t2, t3... and test_with_a_long_name1, test_with_a_long_name2 ... etc) the limit is always 1000.

Thank you very much in advance !

Frederic

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12426944/posting-a-form-with-few-thousand-values. In PHP 5.3.9 they added [max_input_vars](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#max_input_vars)

Comment: If you're working with forms that size, then it's too much for any sane human to want to use

Comment: I'm not going to lie, kind of interested in why you would ever need a page with 1000 checkboxes, even more interested in why you would need 50,000 checkboxes.

Comment: The question is: do you *really* want to use 50 000 POST elements? Like, really really? Can't you somehow split the POST data or refactor it in more "normal" way?

Comment: The 50 000 was a test to check where it fails, if the problem was about size or about number.
I don't know if really need this, i think the answer is yes, here is my need :

I need to manage rights for users, for many elements in an ERP (with many modules), so i have a table with elements and actions (and there are not only add, delete, edit and create) to be checked.
Of course there are shortcuts like "Full access for this element", but i need details like "Full access without this particular action", so i made all actions checkable.

Comment: Thanks for the reply that was probably the problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a setting in php.ini called max_input_vars

More here:

http://anothersysadmin.wordpress.com/2012/02/16/php-5-3-max_input_vars-and-big-forms/

Comment: Default is 1000 so explains the reason why only 1000 are selected for you